# $IterationLimit and parallel computing

Tags: parallelization

Short question:
How can you set `$IterationLimit` for parallel computation?

I thought just setting `$IterationLimit = Infinity` would work but it doesn't. I still get `Iteration limit exceeded` errors. A bit of sample code below:

```
fff[0] = 1;
fff[p_] := fff[p - 1] (*simple function*)
limit = $IterationLimit (*checking $IterationLimit*)

fff[limit + 1000] (*this should give $IterationLimit::itlim error*)

ParallelTable[fff[i], {i, limit + 1000, limit + 1004}] (*this should also give multiple $IterationLimit::itlim errors*)

$IterationLimit = Infinity; (*setting infinite $IterationLimit*)

fff[limit + 1000] (*now this should compute without errors*)

ParallelTable[fff[i], {i, limit + 1000, limit + 1004}] (*this shouldn't give any errors either but for me it throws $IterationLimit::itlim errors*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using parallelization in Mathematica, it is very important to understand that the "parallel threads" are completely separate kernel processes.  Assume that any communication between the main kernel and subkernels needs to be explicit (though there is some automation since version 8: [`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) is done automatically in many cases).

Since `fff` is defined by you, the user, in the `` Global` `` context, the definition of `fff` is automatically distributed to the subkernels (in v8 and later) by `ParallelTable` and you don't need to use `DistributeDefinitions` explicitly.  However, `$IterationLimit` is a system symbol, and it won't be distributed.

If you set `$IterationLimit` on the main kernel, it will only have an effect on the main kernel.

The subkernels have their own `$IterationLimit` which you need to set separately with the aid of `ParallelEvaluate`.  (Do not use `DistributeDefinitions` in this case.)

```
ParallelEvaluate[$IterationLimit = ...]
```